# Fetch correct data from json file with postman

Tags: json, postman, newman

I am currently is running Postman,
also I have made following tests:

```
pm.test("Addition", function () {
    pm.expect(pm.response.text()).to.include("Sture");
});

pm.test("amount", function () {
    pm.expect(pm.response.text()).to.include("60");

});
```

(See my json file below)

```
[
    {
        "MyList": "BeforeCarl",
        "MyListTotalAmount": "90,92",
        "Mylist2": 
        [
            {
                "name": "Dennis",
                "amount": "10,00"
            },
            {
                "name": "Sture",
                "amount": "60,00"
            },
            {
                "name": "Anders",
                "amount": "30,00"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "MyList": "",
        "MyListTotalAmount": "40,00",
        "Mylist2": 
        [
            {
                "name": "Nils",
                "amount": "50,00",
                "": ""
            },
            {
                "name": "Helena",
                "amount": "60,00"
            },
            {
                "name": "Lena",
                "amount": "60,00"
            },
            {
                "name": "Stina",
                "amount": "50,00"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "MyList": "Lars",
        "MyListTotalAmount": "10,00",
        "MyList2": 
        [
            {
                "name": "Sten",
                "amount": "50,00"
            },
            {
                "name": "Stig",
                "amount": "30,00"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

My issue now is I want to fetch:

```
 {
                "name": "Helena",
                "amount": "60,00"
            },
```

What my code does wrong is:

1. it creates first 2 tests (it's not necessary)

2. each of the fetched strings could be anywhere in the JSON.

I want the code to check only for the piece:

```
        {
            "name": "Helena",
            "amount": "60,00"
        }
```

Could someone help me with a solution?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: use json.parse(responseBody) to parse your response, go through your elements then when you match your first pm.expect, test if the second one is correct in your json element. By the way, I'm not familiar with the chai notation, but if you group your two pm.expect in one function, I guess you'll only have one test ...

Comment: Could you help me with a example? 

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, 
if you want to target one piece of code, you can parse your JSON response (by the way, beware of the flags, you have a mix with MyList2 and Mylist2 (lower case 'l') => I renamed all in Mylist2.

When you parse the JSON body, like the example below, you can check values ... I'm not familiar with pm.expect usage so I do it the 'old' way but you'll easily convert it:

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);

console.log("json = " + jsonData)
for (i=0; i< jsonData.length;i++){
    console.log("json[i] = " + jsonData[i].Mylist2[0].name) 
    console.log("json[i].length = " + jsonData[i].Mylist2.length)
    for(j=0;j<jsonData[i].Mylist2.length;j++)
    {
        console.log("    json[i].mylist = " + jsonData[i].Mylist2[j].name)   
        if(jsonData[i].Mylist2[j].name == 'Helena') 
            {
                tests["Helena amount 60 ?"] = jsonData[i].Mylist2[j].amount == '60,00'
            }
    }
}
```

I put a lot of console outputs so you can see what's going on ... the tests[...] is the equivalent of pm.expect.

Comment: you're welcome, if it works well I suggest you mark it as resolved so the community knows it has a solution. cheers.

Comment: I will test this on monday :)  I be back :)

Comment: It looks like the code just loops through the json node list.

In my case I need the loop to check for the 2 items on also they need to be on certain places.